# Adding values to string results in extra white space being added

Tags: c#

The query I execute brings back a result set into the `query` object. To build an object representing the query result I do:

```
var customer = new Customer
{
   CustomerAddress = $"{query.CustomerAddress} {query.City} {query.State} {query.Zip} {query.Country}",
   CustomerPhone = $"{query.PhoneNumber}"
};
```

Now this works fine if all `query` properties are populated. However I realised if I only have the value for `Country` then four extra spaces are placed before the country name.

In this case `customer.CustomerAddress` becomes `"    United Kingdom"`.

When debugging and I place a breakpoint on the query I can see there is no white space in front of `query.Country`, it contains `United Kingdom`.

I know I can use `Trim()` to trim of any white space but I was wondering why do I get this sort of behaviour.

I want to avoid having any white spaces if either of the

- CustomerAddress
- City
- State
- Zip
- Country

are empty in the query result set.

Comment: It's really unclear where the whitespace you're talking about shows up. Is your question: _"If I have no City, how do I prevent two spaces to appear between CustomerAddress and State"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster It shows up just before the country name

Comment: Yeah so if your `query` contains nulls for all properties except `Country`, you'll have four spaces before the country name. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] including example input and output, and explain what you want to change.

Comment: You get whitespace because your string has spaces in it. If `CustomerAddress...Zip` are null/empty the string will interpolate to `"(space)(space)(space)(space){Country}"`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes that's what I'm trying to achieve in case if I don't have either city, state..

Comment: How many whitespaces are there? I'm assuming it's just 1 since you said 'a whitespace'.

Comment: @mindOfAi yes there's only one white space

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with `List<T>`. I suggest you create a [mcve] - all you're seeing is that `$"Foo {""} Bar"` evaluates to `"Foo  Bar"` (with two spaces) which shouldn't be a surprise at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution that keeps your code clean of conditional operators (`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.City) ? "" : " " + query.City` for each property) is to add all properties that are to be printed to an array, and join those with a space when not blank:

```
var addressFields = new string[]
{
    query.CustomerAddress,
    query.City,
    query.State,
    query.Zip,
    query.Country,
}

string address = string.Join(" ", addressFields.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)));
```

Comment: This is better than my option to do the cleanup afterwards

Comment: @Code I've also edited your question to contain only the relevant parts. Please review it and look whether it still asks the question you want answered.

Comment: Yes that looks correct, only part is I wasn't getting 4 spaces added only 1

Comment: @Code that sounds impossible given that code. Perhaps you printed it to HTML, which folds whitespace.

Comment: yes I did print them to HTML so that's what must have happened

Answer (score 3):

Because you have explicitly stated for their to be whitespace in the string. See the following example:

```
string var1 = "hello";
string var2 = "world";
string s = $"{var1} {var2}";
```

This will print:

> hello world

Now if you set `var1` to empty or:

```
var1 = "";
```

You will get:

> (space)world

Because you explicitly stated for there to be a space in the interpolated string. To get around this I would split on spaces, remove empty entries and join with a space:

```
var newS = string.Join(" ", s.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires));
```

Comment: This doesn't look like very time-sensitive code, but building a string to only later split it again doesn't sound optimal. But it is _a_ solution, so have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

`{query.County}` has a space in front of it. Since all other values are empty, your result now looks like `[space]YourCountry`.